# pjsua for android error (cannot locate symbol...)

Tags: android, android-ndk, swig, pjsip

I downloaded the newest Version of pjsip (2.3) source on the official website and installed it correctly.
Then i build the android pjsua sample with the ndk-build command (with swig 2.0.12 installed! swig 3... results in other errors) without any errors. Now I import the sample project in the eclipse ADT from the google site (downloaded and installed this week). Eclipse shows me no problems in the code. But when I downloading it to the phone (Nexus 5) it shows a Error message on the screen.

> UnsatifiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "rand" referenced by "libpjsua.so"...

Project Build Path equals to the Android version of my phone.

I have no Idea how to solve this problem...

Comment: I have solved this problem by my self. The problem was the ndk version. I have installed the version for 64bit smartphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i solved the problem? look at the comment

Step 1: Install the new ndk (for 32bit)

Step 2: reinstall pjsip (with android settings)

Step 3: ndk-build the sample application

Step 4: include project to eclipse

.

.

.